# invoke-expression for SQLCMD -i "test.sql" and put results to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, sqlcmd

I have a huge sql query where I want to run on a remote server from another server via powershell, however I am having trouble trying get the results per column per row of since test.sql produces a table with multiple table and result. I know I can query it using the

```
$ConnectionToServer = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection 
$CommandCMSQry = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
```

Where $CommandCMSQry contains the whole query in a string format. However, I am trying lessen the rows of the script thus I wanted to put the SQL query outside of the PS script.

```
$QryPath = "D:\CNA\DatabaseIntegrityCheck.sql"
invoke-expression "SQLCMD -E -S $InstanceNm -d 'master' -i  $QryPath -b" | Tee-Object -Variable ResultCreateSP | Select-Object name,database_id
$ResultCreateSP
```

Example result:
main result

```
 a b 
 1 foo1
 2 foo2
```

and if I access the columns something with like this

```
write-host "a = " + $ResultCreateSP.name + "b = " + $ResultCreateSP.database_id

a = 1 b = foo1
```

Comment: So what's the question you have?

Comment: my question is how can I assign the invoke-expression results which is in table with 20 rows to be accessible the same as this:

Comment: write-host "a = " + $ResultCreateSP.name + "b = " + $ResultCreateSP.database_id

a = 1 b = foo1